# How to delete an array present inside where_in condition in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I have where_in condition `$this->db->where_in('student_id',$arr);` Now I want to delete the contents present in `$arr` from a table  using this code `$this->db->delete('top_students');` But I got a database error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 2
>   DELETE FROM `top_students` WHERE `student_id` IN()"

How to solve this?

Comment: i think `$arr` is empty - check your values...

Comment: The SQL clearly shows that `$arr` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Check for `empty`  like this ;

```
if ( ! empty($arr))
{
   $this->db->where_in('student_id',$arr);
   $this->db->delete('top_students'); 
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data

Comment: isn't that exactly what OP is doing ?

Comment: Actually $arr is not empty, Sometimes it will be empty if I have not assigned students into my top_students table. AT that time I am getting this error. Thanks for the help

Comment: is my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes. Thankyou @pradeep